# Intuition behind "coupling" of probability distributions.

Tags: probability-theory, coupling

We say that $X$ dominates $Y$ stochastically if for all $x\in\mathbb R$, $F_X(x)\leqslant F_Y(y)$, written $X\geqslant_{\mathrm{st}}Y$. It is a known theorem that if $X\geqslant_{\mathrm{st}}Y$, there exists a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ (namely $([0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]), \mathsf{Leb})$ and random variables $X'$, $Y'$ such that

1. $X' \stackrel d= X$
2. $Y' \stackrel d = Y$
3. $\mathbb P(X'\geqslant Y')=1$.

For example, let $X_n$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb P(X_n=1)=p=1-\mathbb P(X_n=0)$, which models the flips of an unfair coin. Fix $p<q<1$ and define $Z_n$ to be i.i.d. with $\mathbb P(Z_n=1)=\frac{q-p}{1-p}=1-\mathbb P(Z_n=0)$. Define
$$
Y_n = X_n\mathsf 1_{\{X_n=1\}} + Z_n\mathsf 1_{\{X_n=0\}}.
$$
Then any sequence of $Y_n$ has exactly the distribution of tosses made with a second unfair coin with probability heads $q$, but we can directly compare the $X_n$ and $Y_n$ like so:
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum_{j=1}^n X_j>k\right)\leqslant P\left(\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j>k\right)
$$

My question:

> I get that $\mathbb P(Y_n=1)=q=1-\mathbb P(Y_n=0)$ and that the inequality in the above displayed equation holds, but where is the intuition behind defining $Y_n$ like so? Is it just to write $Y_n$ in terms of indicator functions of $X_n$?

Comment: There may be some mistake: Are you intending for $Y_n$ to be integer-valued?  Right now it looks like we can have $Y_1 = (q-p)/(1-p)$ (this occurs whenever $X_1=0$), which does not look like an integer. Also, what is $q$?  If $q<p$ then $Y_1$ can be a negative number.

Comment: I think you mean this: Let $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n, Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n\}$ be mutually independent.  Assume $X_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P[X_i=1]=p$ where $p \in [0,1)$.  Fix $q$ such that $p<q\leq 1$. Assume $Z_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli $P[Z_i=1] = (q-p)/(1-p)$.  Then define $$Y_i = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
X_i &\mbox{ if $X_i=1$} \\
Z_i  & \mbox{ if $X_i=0$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$ Then indeed $Y_i\geq X_i$ for all $i$, and $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli $q$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @Michael I was a bit sloppy in my notation. Allow me to fix it. Edit: Is it correct now?

Comment: The intuition is that, in order to claim $Y_i\geq X_i$ always, we need $Y_i=1$ whenever $X_i=1$. So we _must_ define $Y_i=1$ in the case $X_i=1$.  However, since we want $P[Y_i=1]=q>p$, we must define $Y_i$ to also (sometimes) be 1 when $X_i=0$.  Defining $Y_i$ in terms of $X_i$ is where the "coupling" takes place.

Comment: To make sure you get the concept, you may want to try the case $q<p$:  Assume $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli-$p$ and we want $\{Y_i\}$ i.i.d. Bernoulli-$q$ (where $0<q<p$) such that $Y_i\leq X_i$ for all $i$. How can the $\{Y_i\}$ be defined? [This case is different because now we want $Y_i$ to be either the same or _smaller_ than $X_i$, but the main concept from before can be reused in this situation.]

Comment: Something like $$Y_n = Z_n\mathsf 1_{\{X_n=1\}} + X_n\mathsf 1_{\{X_n=0\}} $$ where $Z_n$ is Bernoulli with parameter $\frac{p-q}{1-q}$?

Comment: That is a good structure but your probabilities do not work. Try computing $P[Y_n=1]$ and you will see the problem and also how to fix.

Comment: @Michael Should it just be $Z_n\sim\mathrm{Ber}(q/p)$ then?

Comment: Yes, assuming $Z_n$ is independent of $X_n$. So then $Y_n=X_nZ_n$.

Comment: Are you sure about $Y_n=Z_nX_n$? It would seem that $\mathbb P(Y_n=0) = (1-q/p)+1-p$ which certainly isn't $1-q$.

Comment: My $Y_n$ is the same as yours: Note that $1_{\{X_n=1\}}=X_n$ whenever $X_n$ is binary-valued (0/1).

Comment: Ah, I see. But what about the $X_n\mathsf 1_{\{X_n=0\}}$ term? Is that just zero, actually?